# Power BI RS web embedding in mobile web browser

Tags: powerbi, embed

We use Power BI reporting server on-premise solution. We can share reports as full screen when I add `?rs:embed=true` to the end of URL published in our intranet.

I switched to Phone Layout section in PowerBI Desktop and prepared a mobile version of the report. But when I open the report in my phone's safari browser, I still see the dekstop version, not mobile.

Is mobile feature supported only on cloud version? How can I open mobile version of my reports in our on-premise reporting server solution?

I tried adding isMobile parameter like; http://companyintranet/webportal/powerbi/Reports/dashboard?rs:embed=true&isMobile=true but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile version is supported in local Power BI Report Server, but you have to use an app to see it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-app-ssrs-kpis-mobile-on-premises-reports